# flexbox does not work in my html, how can i fix it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a trouble with flexbox, i'm just learned it from wesbos (https://github.com/wesbos/What-The-Flexbox/tree/master/flexbox-nav)i tried to create a navbar like him[it's supposed to be looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw6GO.png) but mine isn't working and it turned out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jv6k.png)
Sorry for my bad english, i'm also new to css

```css
.container3 a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.container3 ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
}

.container3 li {
  flex: 1;
}

.container3 a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<nav class="container3">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user"></i> </a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-envelope"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please clearly format your code, better yet, use code snippets to natively run your html & css inside the question

Comment: Css without html is pretty useless. Add it so we can see your problem,!

Comment: sorry it's my bad, it's my first time

Comment: And the URL to where you learned it from doesn't give us any useful information either (because it requires a login.)

Comment: Whay do you mean by it is not working? The two screenshots show little difference regarding flexbox. Can you edit the question clearly stating your problem? (e.g. icons are not aligned at the end of flexbox, or they are not seperated enough? etc)

Comment: @SinanYaman I mean, it's supposed to be looked like a [1] picture, i mean i want all icons and texts separated equally and have a equal hovering background

Comment: You can use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-evenly;` properties which I don't see in the code. Here is the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: @SinanYaman It dont work, it should be like picture [1], all the icons should take up all the left spaces, but they also have a equal surrounding hovering background, all texts too

Comment: @VN-Boy do you have Font Awesome imported in the `<head>` section of your HTML? Without this the icons will not show up.

Comment: @nd03 yes it has, i'm just updated

Comment: @VN-Boy From the screenshots you have attached, I take it that you would like the text on the left and the icons on the right, correct?

Comment: @nd03 yes, it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `flex: 1;` as a substitute for `justify-content: space-around;` on `.container3 ul` then you should also use `text-align: center;` to center the nav items. It also appears there is a `max-width` on the desirable navbar in your screenshots.

```css
.container3 a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.container3 ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container3 li {
  flex: 1;
}

.container3 a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>

<nav class="container3">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user"></i></a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` tag is inline-element, so when it comes to adding margin and padding, browsers treat inline elements differently. You can add left & right margins and padding, but not top & bottom and cannot have a extra width and height set.

So for your purpose to add CSS properties of both `padding: 20px 0;` and `width: 100%;` to take effect on the `a` tag it needs to be converted into a `inline-block` element by adding `display: inline-block;` which respects top & bottom margins and padding as well as respects height and width.

> "it's supposed to be looked like a [1] picture, i mean i want all icons and texts separated equally and have a equal hovering background"

Working Example as per the above comment:

```css
.container3 a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;

  /* Converted <a> element from inline to inline-block */
  display: inline-block;
}

.container3 ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container3 li {
  flex: 1;
}

.container3 social a,
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container3 a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<nav class="container3">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user"></i></a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```